# Access native features of mobile phones in mobile web browser using javascript without using native wrapper

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile-website, native-code

I have one doubt in my mind. can I access device specific functionality in mobile web browser using javascript(or any other library) without using native wrapper around it(like PhoneGap does). I want to develop a **mobile web site** that will access some device specific functionality like Send SMS, Capture Photos, Access Location. All these should be accessed through mobile web browser not using some native code it around for wrapper.
**Is it possible? can I access native features of mobile phones in mobile browser?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you are looking to do. Sending an SMS can be done via the sms: uri in most browsers. The Geolocation API is implemented in pretty much every browser too. Capturing a photo will be a problem though.

Check caniuse.com to see what features are available on your target browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why not, my understanding is that PhoneGap emulate the browser so you are writing a mobile website inside a browser and it is all compiled into a standalone app

I dont see much of a problem with using the same JS/html code for a mobile site

Answer (score 0):

A web page using JavaScript can access whatever the hosting environment allows it to access. Mobile browsers, for security reasons and due to lack of standardisation, don't allow web pages to access many of the native features of mobile devices such as Send SMS.

You might be surprised at what is available to you in the browser nowadays though, you can do some of the things you want to including GeoLocation. See http://www.html5rocks.com/ to get an idea of what is available now.

However, if you need access to things that aren't exposed via the standard browser APIs, then you need to host your web page in a native shim, such as PhoneGap/Cordova, that will provide access to those extra missing features that it is able to provide in a non-standard way as it is running in a different security context.